# Inserting new form element with Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

new to Javascript/JQuery.

How would I create a form element like this:

```
<input type="number" name="coupon" id="coupon" min="1.0" max="5.0" step="0.5" value="2.5"/>
```

such that I can allocate min/max/value values based on variables I'm storing.

Also, how would I insert it in the proper place in the form?

Comment: can you post more code? where do you have the variables? in javascript or database/sql?

Comment: The documentation and literally hundreds of tutorials on the web describe how to create elements and place them into the DOM. Which part exactly is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  How are you defining the proper place in the form?  Where are you getting the variables from?

Answer (score 2):

to create a form input element..

```
 var max="2",min="1",value="test"; //your values
 var createdInput=$('<input>',{
                type:"number",
                name:"coupon",
                id:"coupon",
                min:min,
                max:max,
                step:"0.5"
                value:value
 });
```

this is to create an input element..and to place it ina form you can use.. `append()` or `after()` , `prepend()` .. any method for DOM insertion(which actually depends on where you want).

```
$('#formID').append(createdInput); //this will append the input to form
$('#elementID').after(createdInput); //this will add the created input after the element in the selector
```